# Thrift 0.9 PHP server missing Processor

Tags: php, thrift

I'm writing an application that communicates by Thrift. I'm using Thrift 0.9.0 (installed via homebrew on OSX). I have a working Java server and client, but I'm struggling to write a PHP server, as the *Processor class isn't being generated.

The PHP documentation for Thrift is [essentially absent](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/php/), but I'm expecting the *Processor class to be generated because:

- The [current (21c0a850) PhpServer.php in the Thrift tutorial](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/21c0a85079e3e1b5ee475bd6654512079fe5df68/tutorial/php/PhpServer.php) references a CalculatorProcessor class.
- Generating the Java code for the tutorial generates a Calculator.Processor class

When I generate the PHP code from the tutorial.thrift file (`thrift -r --gen php:namespace tutorial.thrift`), however, the resulting Calculator.php doesn't contain a CalculatorProcessor class.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of writing this question prompted me to spot the answer!

I was generating `php:namespace`, but that was a hold-over from using Thrift 0.8.0. In fact, 'namespace' doesn't exist in 0.8 (presumably because namespaces are always added to generated PHP in 0.9). The output of `thrift --help` does list `php:server`, which "generates PHP server stubs". This means, apparently, generating the PHP *Processor class.

Comment: (Thrift 0.9.1). I've used [thrift --gen php thrift/tutorial.thrift] instead of [thrift --gen php:server thrift/tutorial.thrift]

Answer (score 1):

I've got a very similar application as you defined (Java Server with PHP Client).

I've got following thrift definitions file:

```
namespace java com.blogspot.symfonyworld.wealthylaughingduck.thrift.generated
namespace php SymfonyWorld.WealthyLaughingDuck

# definitions below
```

and I run the following commands to regenerate the thrift classes:

```
thrift -r --gen java -out src/main/java src/submodules/commons/thrift/service.thrift
thrift -r --gen php:oop,namespace,autoload -out src/main/php/packages src/submodules/commons/thrift/service.thrift
```

And it works like a charm :) Take a look at my [github application](https://github.com/wealthy-laughing-duck/wealthy-laughing-duck) - it works out of the box (you may watch Java log4j output as you click in the interface).

Comment: I'd actually already found that on GitHub! (Turns out not many repos have "new TSimpleServer" in PHP code.) I used it to reassure myself my PHP code wasn't too crazy, so thanks.

Comment: Although, actually, I just tried `php:oop,namepsace,autoload` on the thrift tutorial, and the CalculatorProcessor wasn't generated. What version of thrift are you using?

The following returns nothing for me:
`git clone git@github.com:apache/thrift.git && cd thrift/tutorial/ && thrift -r --gen php:oop,namespace,autoload tutorial.thrift && grep Processor gen-php/tutorial/Calculator.php`

But then running this returns a line:
`rm -rf gen-php/ && thrift -r --gen php:oop,namespace,autoload,server tutorial.thrift && grep Processor gen-php/tutorial/Calculator.php`

Comment: I'm using thrift version 0.9.0. Well, I don't understand those line sequence: git clone thrift - cd thrift/tutorial - thrift generate. I'm not sure you can't do it this way, but I'm pretty sure this is not the suggested way. Download the sources and **compile** it locally so that is goes to `/usr/local/bin/thrift` and then you'll have thrift in the command line.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't mean to illustrate compiling; those commands assume thrift is already on the system. I was just saying I don't get a CalculatorProcessor class if the --gen flag you suggested.